# How to back up a postgresql database from within psql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am within psql and am wondering if there is a way to backup/restore databases from this command shell.  I have read of pg_dump, but that fails with "syntax error at or near pg_dump".

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can always run shell command directly from [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) session using `\! [ command ]` syntax, for example:

```
\! pg_dump -Fc -f D:\postgres.dump -U postgres postgres
```

Of course it's not so common to execute [`pg_dump`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) or [`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) in such way, but it's possible.

Chapter [VI. Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/reference.html) contains list of all SQL commands and applications (both client and server).

Answer (score 7):

pg_dump is a system command, not a command that you can use from within psql.  From within psql you might be looking for something more like 'copy'.  You can see it documented here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

I'm not a Postgresql expert, but I have found the Postgresql online documentation thorough and professional.  I recommend browsing through it if you're planning on using Postgresql to a significant degree.

Comment: I had the same issue. I was in psql and had to \q to get back to the shell then run it.