# Heroku postgresql snapshot dump file

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pgadmin

Is there a way to import `.dump` file from Heroku to `pgadmin`?

I've tried something like below in SQL editor

`pg_restore -c -d virtual b003.dump`

but I'm getting

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_restore"
LINE 1: pg_restore -c -d virtual b003.dump
        ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "pg_restore"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7265704/398670

Answer (score 1):

[`pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html) is a command-line tool, not a SQL command. pgAdmin has its [own UI](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/restore.html) for restoring DB dumps