# PostgreSQL: Database backup and Recovery?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

What is the procedure to take database backup and recovery in PostgreSQL 9.3?

I am using SQL Dump for the same, but getting an error near pg_dump.

--Example

```
pg_dump testdb > backupfile
```

--Error occurred

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_dump"  
LINE 1: pg_dump testdb > backupfile
```

Comment: Are you taking backup of local database or remote database ?

Comment: @Satyam Koyani, Local database.

Comment: As your error pointing to some syntax error.Check your database name and dbuser.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani, Yes its right.

Comment: pg_dump is a utility program. You should run this from a command prompt, not a psql monitor or pgAdmin III.

Comment: Y'know, the first Google hit is [How to back up a postgresql database from within psql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265704/how-to-back-up-a-postgresql-database-from-within-psql) ...

Comment: @Patrick, After you said. I am trying the same by using command prompt but getting FATAL error of authentication fail. I tried with all passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below command to take Database backup locally

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -Fc -f FileName.backup -w DBName
```

If you want to take database backup remotely Than use Remote IPAddress in place of 127.0.0.1.